# Program that checks the connectivity of the graph produces a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I'm currently making a program to check whether a graph is fully connected. My approach is to use a depth-first search traversal algorithm, and just ensure that every node is connected. However, I'm currently getting a segmentation fault as soon as I compile the program. I've tried everything, I haven't been able to find the issue. Here's my current code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>> adj;
vector<bool> visited;

void dfs(int v) {
    visited[v] = true;
    for (int u : adj[v]) {
        if (!visited[u])
            dfs(u);
    }
}

int main() {
    bool connected = false;
    adj[1].push_back(2);
    adj[2].push_back(3);
    adj[3].push_back(1);
    dfs(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (visited[i]) {
            connected = true;
        }
        else
            connected = false;
    }
    if (connected) {
        cout << "connected" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "it isn't connected" << endl;
}
```

Any suggestions, or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this post!

Comment: [Rubber Ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like to know how you plan to `adj[1].push_back(2);` before allocating `adj[1]`;

Comment: Same issue for `visited`. Its size is 0.

Comment: Note that besides, the way you check connectivity at the end is not correct. A graph is connected if *all* nodes are visited.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @user4581301 and Damien! I can't believe I didn't find that. Damien, shouldn't the algorithm work though? If we have any false values in visited, it means that we haven't traversed the whole graph, meaning it isn't connected. Or have I not used the visited vector correctly?

Comment: @Damien it wouldn't let me tag you in the previous comment ^

Comment: @user12223445 You can only target one person in a comment! IIt was too difficult to explain everything in a comment, So i have posted an answer.

Comment: @Damien Thank you so much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was the fact that you forgot to set the sizes of the vectors. That was causing the segmentation fault.

But there are several other issues with your code:

1. The logic to detect connectivity is not correct. In practice, with your code, the connection of the last node only determines the connectivity of the graph. And this last node is always connected, as you start from this node for the DFS.
2. Here `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` you use a 0-indexing. You forgot that in the rest of the code, you are using 1-indexing. The best will be to use 0-indexing everywhere. Nevertheless, in the follwing code, I keep the 1-indexing, to show how to cope with it, in particular concerning the size of the arrays.
3. You should avoid the use of magic constant like `3` in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//using namespace std;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj;
std::vector<bool> visited;

void dfs(int v){
    visited[v] = true;
    for (int u : adj[v]) {
        if (!visited[u])
            dfs(u);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n_nodes = 3;
    visited.resize(n_nodes+1);      // <-- !!!
    adj.resize(n_nodes+1);      // <-- !!!

    adj[1].push_back(2);
    adj[2].push_back(3);
    adj[3].push_back(1);
    dfs(3);
    
    bool connected = true;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n_nodes; i++) { // 1-indexed
        if(!visited[i]){
            connected = false;
        }
    }
    if(connected) {
        std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "it isn't connected" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't even know I should avoid constants! Yeah that makes sense, can't believe I didn't think of that.